# Combine several dcast data.table (which share same key) efficiently

Tags: r, data.table, dcast

Here is the simple problem I'm trying to solve: I have a data.table like following table, and I'm trying to use `dcast.data.table` function to calculate number of advancement for each group, but also I'm interested to calculate `median` of grades in each group:

```
set.seed(10);
DT = data.table(GROUP = sample(c("a","b","c"),100,replace = T), 
                ADVANCED = sample(c("ADVANCED","DROP"),100,replace = T),
                GRADE = sample(1:10,100, replace=T))

     GROUP ADVANCED GRADE
  1:     b ADVANCED     3
  2:     a ADVANCED     6
  3:     b ADVANCED     7
  4:     c ADVANCED     9

 95:     b     DROP     6
 96:     c ADVANCED     5
 97:     a     DROP    10
 98:     b ADVANCED     1
 99:     c     DROP     6
100:     a     DROP     2
     GROUP ADVANCED GRADE
```

Essentially here is the result I'm looking for:

```
result = merge(
  dcast.data.table(DT,.Primitive("~")(GROUP,ADVANCED)),
  dcast.data.table(DT,.Primitive("~")(GROUP,.),
                   value.var="GRADE", 
                   fun.aggregate=median));

setnames(result,".","MEDIAN_GRADE")

   GROUP ADVANCED DROP MEDIAN_GRADE
1:     a       17   19            6
2:     b       20   21            7
3:     c       13   10            6
```

Now I'm wondering how can I do it without making two separate dcast tables and merge at the end. I'm dealing with many row and column in my tables and grouping by key is a bottleneck. I'm wondering is there a better way to calculate this?

** Since my first question was vague I edit completely (thanks to Frank and Akrun for their feedback).

Comment: You should probably use `set.seed` before making random examples.

Comment: There's `reshape2::dcast(DT, GROUP ~ ADVANCED, margins="ADVANCED")` but you lose access to the improvements made in `data.table::dcast`. It looks like `margins` never got implemented: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1214

Comment: This looks like a completely different question from the one you posted earlier

Comment: you are right, we could solve previous questions with many different ways .

Comment: I agree with you, please accept my apology.

Comment: The `rhs` of `~` is different for both `dcast`, so there is no way to do that in a single `dcast`.  I posted an option with `on`

Comment: thanks for the answer, using `on` instead of `merge` make my code 30% faster. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the updated question

```
setnames(dcast(DT, GROUP~ADVANCED, length)[dcast(DT, GROUP~., median),
            on = "GROUP"], ".", "MEDIAN_GRADE")[]
#   GROUP ADVANCED DROP MEDIAN_GRADE
#1:     a       17   19            6
#2:     b       20   21            7
#3:     c       13   10            6
```

Or a faster approach would be to group by 'GROUP', get the `median` of 'GRADE' and then do the join `on` the `dcast` output

```
DT[,.(MEDIAN_GRADE = median(GRADE)) , .(GROUP)][
              dcast(DT, GROUP ~ ADVANCED, length), on = 'GROUP']
```

Comment: More generally `dcast(DT, GROUP ~ ADVANCED)[, SIZE := Reduce(\`+\`, .SD), .SDcols = unique(DT$ADVANCED)][]`

Comment: the real function that I'm interested is more complex and I cannot sum all columns to get that directly. I added this to the question. thanks

Comment: @Mahdi That's too vague for me to understand.

Comment: @MahdiJadaliha  You showed a simple example and expected result for others to code.  So how do we know what kind of dataset you have

Comment: sorry I will fix it in a minute with more elaborated example.

Comment: Yeah, I think this final approach with `on` is the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks @akrun, this answer improved the performance of my code considerably. it would be great if you remove the answer to the first question to avoid confusions. :)

Comment: @MahdiJadaliha  Okay, I removed it.

Comment: @Akrun, I changed the number of rows in data.table to 50000000 and now the approach your proposed at last is crashing 1 out of 3 times (approx.) on my computer. The first approach still working fine and it is 30% faster than the original merge approach, but it is 20% slower than your latest approach which is crushing sometimes.

Comment: @MahdiJadaliha  Okay, there might be a limit on the number of rows.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could compute in long form and then reshape:

```
dcast(DT[, rbind(
  .SD[, .(v = .N), by=.(stat = paste0("n.",ADVANCED))],
  .(stat = "med", v = as.numeric(median(GRADE)))
), by=GROUP], GROUP ~ stat)

   GROUP med n.ADVANCED n.DROP
1:     a   6         17     19
2:     b   7         20     21
3:     c   6         13     10
```

Obviously, this still involves tons of manual fiddling. It also requires that your stats all be numeric (since they are stacked in the `stat` column together before the `dcast`). I think the approach in @akrun's answer -- like `DT[, f(...), by=GROUP][dcast(DT, GROUP ~ x), on=GROUP]` -- is much better, limiting the `dcast` to only those calls that need it.